A column value becomes all 1s after pyspark dataframe toPandas()
I encountered a strange error. All of the value of a column become completely the same after toPandas().
I have a binary classification dataset:
dataframe schema:
| id | feature | label | 
| xx | xxxx    | 0     |
| xx | xxxx    | 1     |

The dataframe are separated into positive and negative by labels, and processed differently, followed by union. However, the value of label become complete same (all 1s) after toPandas() operation. The code is like the following:
def sampling(df, k):
    w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.rand(1234))
    df = df.withColumn('row', F.row_number().over(w)).filter(F.col('row')<=k).drop('row') 
    return df

#separate df into two
pos_df = df.filter(F.col('label')==1)
neg_df = df.filter(F.col('label')==0)
#apply different processing
pos_sample_df = sampling(pos_df, 5)
neg_sample_df = sampling(neg_df, 4)
#union
df = pos_sample_df.union(neg_sample_df)
pdf = df.toPandas()

I found the label column of pdf become all 1s. However, if I directly check the df before toPandas(), the label column still have both 1 or 0 values.
I've tried debug the code and finally found if the order of union changed. It would works well. I cannot understand what happened.
df2 = neg_sample_df.union(pos_sample_df) 
pdf2 = df2.toPandas() # works well


Could you provide sample data which reproduces the problem?
